# Using external forms in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm

Just a quick question are there any issues  using a Form to create a Web browser in a WPF application and what are the reasons behind it. Or is it a badly designed application? It is the only one I have seen though I have never seen such a implementation. What could be the WPF equivalent to this?

here is some example code of a WPF Application using a Form.

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;


     private static long RunWebBrowserFormAndGetCode()
    {
        Form webBrowserForm = new Form();
        WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        long userID = 0;
        var uri = new Uri(@"https://somesite.com/get");
        webBrowser.Url = uri;
        webBrowserForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        webBrowserForm.Controls.Add(webBrowser);
        webBrowserForm.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"bla.icon");
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler documentCompletedHandler = (s, e1) =>
        {
            try
            {
                string[] clientID = webBrowser.Url.Segments[2].Split('/');
                if (clientID[0].All(char.IsDigit))
                {
                    userID = Int64.Parse(clientID[0]);
                    webBrowserForm.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return;
            }
        };
```

Comment: WPF and Winforms interop reasonably well. What problems are you expecting? You haven't even shown the code that _shows_ the `webBrowserForm` object; I can't imagine how anyone could provide anything specific regarding your actual use of the form in WPF. As with anything, there are right ways and wrong ways to do things. If it works, you're probably doing it the right way. Please post a new question, if you have something _specific_. Provide a good [mcve] with a precise explanation of what that code does and how it's different from what you want.

Comment: Peter that is a complete example it will create a FORM as a empty form. and calls the site that it needs to I removed certain code to make it more censored for use on stack over flow. If you actually Bothered to have run it you would of seen that it is working as a complete set of code, and you say for me to comply with the stackoverflow policy when In fact I have I asked for a recommendation and a explanation on and if any issue running a form in a wpf application.